# Getting row value of a dynamic table

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have created a dynamic table by using this api : https://bi.syncfusion.com/northwindservice/api/orders

https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=local.wusodi&right=local.fenuzo

[image]

**Service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OrdersService {

  constructor(public http:HttpClient) { }

  getAllItems() {
    return this.http.get(
        "https://bi.syncfusion.com/northwindservice/api/orders"
      )
      
  }
}
```

**HTML file**

```html
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Ship City</th>
                        <th>Ship Country</th>
                        <th>UnitPrice</th>
                        <th>UnitPrice</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>ProductName</th>
                        <th>QuantityPerUnit</th>
                        <!-- <th>UnitPrice (Products)</th> -->
                        <th>UnitsInStock</th>
                        <th>UnitsOnOrder</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr (click)="openModal()" *ngFor="let order of allOrders" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': getColor(order.ShipCountry, order.ShipCity)}">
                
                    <td>{{order.ShipCity}}</td>
                    <td>{{order.ShipCountry}}</td>
                    <td>{{order.UnitPrice}}</td>
                    <td>{{order.Quantity}}</td>
                    <td>{{order.Discount}}</td>
                    <td>{{order.ProductName}}</td>
                    <td>{{order.QuantityPerUnit}}</td>
                    <!-- <td>{{order.UnitPrice (Products)}}</td> -->
                    <td>{{order.UnitsInStock}}</td>
                    <td>{{order.UnitsOnOrder}}</td>

                </tr>
            </table>
```

**TS file**

```js
  getAllOrders(){
    this.ordersService.getAllItems().subscribe((data:any)=>{
      this.allOrders = data.Items;
      console.log("All Items:", this.allOrders);
      this.count = data.Count;
      console.log("Count is:", this.count);
    })  
  }
```

So my question is - How do I get a specific row's value? Even just to console.log that row by clicking on it.

Unfortunatly, the objects from the API dont have any unique ID that could be of use.

Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr (click)="openModal(order)" *ngFor="let order of allOrders" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': getColor(order.ShipCountry, order.ShipCity)}">


openModel(order):void{   console.log(order) }
```

when u pass the order click method,we will get the row value after that you will write the logic